# Error en CRUD usando Summernote

Tags: javascript, php, crud, summernote

Chicos tengo el siguiente codigo

```
    <!--Update modal-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="updateModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" 
     aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Actualizar</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="updateseccion">Seccion</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="updateseccion" 
                            placeholder="Ingresa tu Seccion">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="updatecontenido">Contenido</label>
                            <textarea class="summernote" id="updatecontenido" 
                            placeholder="Ingresa tu Contenido"></textarea>
                        </div>                     
                    </div>
<script>
$('#updatecontenido').summernote({
lang: 'es-ES',
placeholder: 'Ingrese su contenido',
tabsize: 2,
height: 300
});
</script>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="updateDetails()">Actualizar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                        <input type="hidden" id="hiddendata">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

el script del CRUD que estoy usando es el siguiente

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        displayData();
    });
    // display function
    function displayData(){
        var displayData="true";
        $.ajax({
            url:"contenido/crud/display.php",
            type:'post',
            data:{
                displaySend:displayData
            },
            success:function(data,status){
            $('#displayDataTable').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function addcontenido(){
    var seccionAdd=$('#completeseccion').val();
    var contenidoAdd=$('#completcontenido').val();

    $.ajax({
        url:"contenido/crud/insert.php",
        type:'post',
        data:{
                seccionSend:seccionAdd,
                contenidoSend:contenidoAdd,
        },
        success:function(data,status){
          //funcion para mostar los datos;
          //console.log(status);
          $('#completeModal').modal('hide');

          displayData();
        }

     });
}

//Eliminar Guardados
function DeleteUser(deleteid){
    $.ajax({
            url:"contenido/crud/delete.php",
            type:'post',
            data:{
                deletesend:deleteid
            },
            success:function(data,status){
                displayData();
            }
    });
}


// Update de las funciones
function GetDetails(updateid){
    $('#hiddendata').val(updateid);

    $.post("contenido/crud/update.php",{updateid:updateid},function(data,status){
        var userid=JSON.parse(data);
        $('#updateseccion').val(userid.seccion);
        $('#updatecontenido').val(userid.contenido);
    });

    $('#updateModal').modal("show");
}


//funcion para actualizar evento onclick 
function updateDetails(){
    var updateseccion=$('#updateseccion').val();
    var updatecontenido=$('#updatecontenido').val();
    var hiddendata=$('#hiddendata').val();

    console.log("MODIFICAR")
    $.ajax({
            url:"contenido/crud/update.php",
            type:'post',
            data:{
                updateseccion:updateseccion,
                updatecontenido:updatecontenido,
                hiddendata:hiddendata          
            },
            success:function(data,status){
                   $('#updateModal').modal('hide');
                displayData();
            }
    });

}
    </script>
```

Los errores que tengo son los siguientes:

1. Asi como esta carga el contenido de `updateseccion` pero no carga nada en el area de texto `updatecontenido` solo se muestra **Ingrese su contenido**
2. Si borro el script de summernote se carga el contenido de manera perfecta pero en formato codigo html ejemplo: `<p>BBBB</p>` pero obviamente no carga la herramienta summernote.

He intentado hacer algo asi:

```
<script>
// Recupera el contenido existente
const existingContent = '{{ existingContent }}';

// Establece el contenido inicial en el textarea
$('#updatecontenido').val(userid.contenido);

// Inicializa el editor Summernote
$('#updatecontenido').summernote({
lang: 'es-ES',
placeholder: 'Ingrese su contenido',
tabsize: 2,
height: 300
});
</script>
```

Pero sin exito.

Answer (score 0):

El error lo tenia en la carga de

```
  <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
  <script src="'.$pag_web.'/funciones/jquery/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
```

lo estaba cargando al principio y al final del código y eso generaba un error, he verificado y corregido mi codigo y ha funcionado perfectamente.